# Entity Framework include property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, include, linq-to-entities

Originally, I had a basic `Client` consisting of just:

```
public class Client : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My `User`s, along with the usual `Name` fields, etc. have a `Client`:

```
public class User : Entity
{
    [Required, MinLength(4), Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required, MinLength(2), Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required, MinLength(2), Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required, EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    ...
    [Required]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

My `Get` method:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string[] includeProperties = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (includeProperties != null)
            query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (q, s) => q.Include(s));

        query = query.Where(x => !x.Deleted);

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query).ToList() : query.ToList();
    }
```

All this was fine. So, on to the problem: It's actually with my Client, since adding an additional property for an `AccountManager` (i.e. a `User`), it doesn't like me.

```
public class Client : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public CompanyType CompanyType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ClientStatus Status { get; set; }

    [SomethingInHere?]
    public virtual User AccountManager { get; set; }

    public DateTime? AccessFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AccessTo { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I've added "AccountManager" to the `INCLUDE_STRING` for the `Get`s and even recently tried using various `ForeignKey`/`Required` data annotations but can't get it to pull out the AccountManager `User` along with it.

And with that, I assume it's part of, if not the whole reason that I can no longer pull out any `User`s at all.

In short, my grasp of EF's relationship handling is somewhat limited, and it would appear that my Googling abilities today aren't up to scratch.

Many `User`s to a `Client`. One `User` as `AccountManager` for each `Client`. Why is this so hard for me?

Edit: Rounded answer.

Added in modelbuilder parts:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Client)
            .WithMany(x => x.Users);

modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.AccountManager);
```

and altered the `Client` to include a list of users:

```
public class Client : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public CompanyType CompanyType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ClientStatus Status { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual User AccountManager { get; set; }

    public DateTime? AccessFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AccessTo { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Together that made EF happy enough to pull it all out properly.

Comment: You said "*This is not using Code First*" in a comment below. How did you add then "*an additional property for an AccountManager*" to the class? In the visual designer surface? Or in an EDMX file?

Comment: @Slauma Ah, sorry, apparently I lied, we do use code first, I was thinking about the code first _migration_ that we don't use (not for this project anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that Code-First conventions are not doing the right thing that you actually want. After you've added the `AccountManager` property Entity Framework conventions are detecting a pair of two reference navigation properties, namely `User.Client` and `Client.AccountManager`. EF assumes that they are the navigation ends of the same single relationship which then must be a one-to-one relationship because the properties are references and not collections.

But you said that you actually want: *"Many Users to a Client. One User as AccountManager for each Client"*. These are *two* relationships and not only one, i.e. each of the two references belongs to another relationship. To achieve this you must override the convention explicitly using Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasRequired(u => u.Client)
    .WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
    .HasOptional(c => c.AccountManager)
    .WithMany();
```

Comment: This is pretty damn close to the answer. Added in the modelbuilder parts as well as adding a List<User> property to the Client - seems EF wasn't too happy about the semi-circular relations between the two tables, and the additional property helped set it straight.

Answer (score 0):

This might qualify as more of a comment, but too much to fit there...

1. Put all your custom stuff aside and try querying EF directly as it was intended. This will at least rule out any issues with your own code vs. how the entities are set up (right now its hard to tell since we can't see where the problem might be with this limited code sample).
2. A better way (IMO) to use `Include`'s is to use the strongly typed version: `query.Include(u => u.Client)`. Makes your code less prone to runtime errors.
3. Show the query that is failing to bring back a related property, and post all the relevant entities/properties. Are you including a Foreign Key Id property that matches EF conventions? Is this using EF Code First or EDMX model?

**EDIT** - [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713299) may help you set up the relationship. I'm also noticing your `User` Entity is missing a `ClientId` property (and `Client` is missing `AccountManagerId`). In order to pull the "Navigation Property" (a term you might want to include in your Google searching if you haven't already) it would need to know what Foreign Key property to join on.

Comment: Edited my question, added the full Get code. This is not using Code First.

Comment: Switching to use full query.Include(x => x.Client) for Users or query.Include(x => x.AccountManager) for Clients doesn't seem to have much of an effect. Users are missing their Clients and Clients are missing their AccountManagers (but at least I have the objects, I guess)

Comment: @Krenom: Updated answer with some more info.